# WPF DataGrid row's color multibound (also) to own IsSelected property?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with ItemsSource connected to SQL table. I need to color-code row backgrounds. So I set a Style for DataRow :

```
     <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource rowColor}">
// here I'm passing DataRowView that gives me access to row data - this is working well
                                <Binding /> 
// below part is not working (compiling, but passing nothing)
                                <Binding Source="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" Path="IsSelected" /> 
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Thing is that I need to set many colors, depending on row's data. I.e. Green, Yellow, Red... It's for immediate visual recognition of each item's status. This part works perfectly.

But I also need to color-code each row, when it's in selected state. Otherwise, once selected, they all have that useless default RoyalBlue background. so for selected rows I would need to set DarkGreen, DarkYellow, DarkRed... etc. Hence the MultiBinding and my attempt to pass own IsSelected property to the converter. And that's not working. Whatever I tried (and I tried a lot, also other properties), inside my Convert() function, values[0] is ok (DataRowView), but values[1] is always a DependencyObject.Unset.

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the `RelativeSource` property instead of `Source`:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="IsSelected" />
```

Comment: Thank You. working. well - almost. setting color for selected row is not working at all, but it made me look forward and it's doable (using same bindings) for a cell.

Comment: @Vojtek: Please remember to accept the answer if your original issue has been solved.